# How can I remove the space after qlineedit get text?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8, readlines

I am programming an app with python 3.8.3 and pyQt5. Here's a part of my code:

```
def logind(self):
        datas=open('NeveshtarUsers.txt', 'r')
        data=datas.readlines()
        print(data)
        n=self.user.text()
        print(n,'\n')
        print(data[1])
        if (data[1])==(n,'\n'):
            print('yeeeeesssss!')
```

I checked that `data[1]` is exactly equal `self.user.text()`, but when I code

```
n=self.user.text()
```

the output has an space after text, but data[1] don't have an space. so I can't continue my project.
Please help me, if you can.

Comment: The space is coming from (n, '\n). Try using (n + '\n') instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a trailing \n char. Try

```
n=self.user.text()
n.rstrip("\n")
```

To remove the newline